# Multiple ability score increases for multi-classes

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, statistics

If two or more classes each impart ability score increases do they accumulate or is there some sort of maximum increase due to all classes’ benefits?

For example, if class A allows an ability score increase, resulting in an increase of a particular ability score at a certain level, and class B does the same (possibly to a lesser or greater extent for that particular score) at possibly a different level, does the player apply both benefits? What limitations, if any, apply?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It would be helpful to understand the actual problem that caused you to raise the question. The typical ability score increases granted by leveling are the same for all classes, so this could help to understand what you specifically are struggling with.

Comment: There is no class feature that increases one particular stat, so we’re gonna need more details about what exactly you’re referring to. Are you familiar with the *Basic Rules* or the class descriptions in the *Player’s Handbook*?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov nitpicking, I believe the Barbarian capstone feature does, but generally your point stands.

Comment: @JoelHarmon I can nitpick too: the barb’s 20th level feature increase *two* particular stats :P Also it’s a 20th level feature and this question is about multiclassing.

Answer (score 8):

Ability Score Improvements (ASI) are linked to the number of levels in each class. For instance, for Fighters, the ASIs are summarized in the Fighter's [Quick Build](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#QuickBuild5) table and described in "[Ability Score Improvement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#FighterAbilityScoreImprovement)".

As an example, a 5th level Fighter / 9th level Rogue would have gotten one ASI when leveling up to Fighter 4, another leveling up to Rogue 4, and a third leveling up to Rogue 8.

ASIs for different classes are not linked to a specific ability. As the text in each class says, under Ability Score Improvement:

> ...you can increase one ability score of your choice by 2, or you can increase two ability scores of your choice by 1. As normal, you can’t increase an ability score above 20 using this feature.

Note the cap of 20, above.

Finally, the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#SageAdviceCompendium) adds clarification on [Multiclassing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#Multiclassing), and says in part:

> **Are ability score improvements class-level dependent, rather than total level?**
> Ability score improvements are based on your level in a particular class, not your total character level if you multiclass. For instance, if you’re a 4th-level multiclass character, you haven’t yet received the Ability Score Improvement feature because you haven’t attained 4th level in one of your classes.

Answer (score 4):

### This sounds like a misunderstanding of how leveling works

From the description, it sounds like you are asking about simultaneously leveling both classes when you "level up".

When reading the [Character Advancement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/step-by-step-characters#CharacterAdvancement) table, it shows that when you gain a certain amount of XP your character becomes a new level. This level is your overall character level and can be separate from your class level. If you are only one class, then your character level and class level are the same value.

Under the [Multiclass](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/customization-options#Multiclassing) explanation:

> With this rule, you have the option of gaining a level in a new class whenever you advance in level, **instead of gaining a level in your current class.** Your levels in all your classes are added together to determine your character level. **For example, if you have three levels in wizard and two in fighter, you're a 5th-level character**.

So as you increase in levels, you can choose to advance one class or another, but not both at once. Therefore, you will only get Class A stat increase when you reach specific levels for that class. You will not get Class B's stat increase unless you decide to increase Class B, which means you gain nothing new from Class A.

As an impractical example, you can have three levels in Barbarian, three levels in Fighter, and three levels in Rogue. You would be a 9th-level character, but you have not reached 4th-level in any one class to get the ASI feature that all classes receive.

Nothing "accumulates"; it's strictly one class level at a time, only gaining the bonuses/features when you put enough levels into that particular class.

The term "level' has different, and too many, meanings in D&D and has had from the beginning.

Your 7th-level character is a 3rd-level fighter and 4th-level wizard that can cast 1st-level spells using their 2nd-level spell slots while on the 5th level of the dungeon.

---

Now, if this is not the misunderstanding, please update the question to explain the exact problem.